# Xml Parsing activity force closes if no connection

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am using following code from a tutorial , code works great but the app force closes if there is no connection or incase of slow connection.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView mListView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // URL to the XML data
        String strUrl = "http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/p/demo1/countries_xml.php/countries/";

        // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download xml data
        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        // Starting the download process
        downloadTask.execute(strUrl);

        // Getting a reference to ListView of activity_main
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);

    }

    /** A method to download xml data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
        }
        return data;
    }

    /** AsyncTask to download xml data */
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
        String data = null;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try{
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            // The parsing of xml data is done in a non-ui thread
            ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();

            // Start parsing xml data
            listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    /** AsyncTask to parse xml data and load ListView */
    private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>{

        StringReader reader;

        // Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strXml) {
            try{
                reader = new StringReader(strXml[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("XML Exception1",e.toString());
            }

            // Instantiating xml parser class
            CountryXmlParser countryXmlParser = new CountryXmlParser();

            // A list object to store the parsed countries list
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries = null;

            try{
                // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                countries = countryXmlParser.parse(reader);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }

            // Keys used in Hashmap
            String[] from = { "country","flag","details"};

            // Ids of views in listview_layout
            int[] to = { R.id.tv_country,R.id.iv_flag,R.id.tv_country_details};

            // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
            // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), countries, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);

            return adapter;
        }

        /** Invoked by the Android when "doInBackground" is executed */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {

            // Setting adapter for the listview
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

            for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
                String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
                ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

                HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hm.put("flag_path",imgUrl);
                hm.put("position", i);

                // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in the listview
                imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
            }
        }
    }

    /** AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView */
    private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

            InputStream iStream=null;
            String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("flag_path");
            int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(imgUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                // Getting Caching directory
                File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

                // Temporary file to store the downloaded image
                File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+position+".png");

                // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);

                // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);

                // Flush the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.flush();

                //Close the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.close();

                // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
                HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                // Storing the path to the temporary image file
                hmBitmap.put("flag",tmpFile.getPath());

                // Storing the position of the image in the listview
                hmBitmap.put("position",position);

                // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
                return hmBitmap;

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
            // Getting the path to the downloaded image
            String path = (String) result.get("flag");

            // Getting the position of the downloaded image
            int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

            // Getting adapter of the listview
            SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter ) mListView.getAdapter();

            // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the listview
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);

            // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter
            hm.put("flag",path);

            // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Show the stack trace please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning null if an exception is thrown during doInBackground(), but then you're accessing result in onPostExecute() and not handling the null case. You need to verify that result is not null before you try to access it. Like so:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
        if (result != null) {
            // Getting the path to the downloaded image
            String path = (String) result.get("flag");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check if your application has internet access, before making calls that require it.

Following methods check if you have internet access. Use it before you need to do internet calls. If it returns false, show the user a notification saying that internet is required.

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    try {
        InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com"); //You can replace it with your name

        if (ipAddr.equals("")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Also, add these permissions if you haven't already:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Use it like this

```
if (isInternetAvailable() {
    // available network
} else {
    // no network
}
```